# Matrix transformation: not how to interpret this question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It says "By computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrices, give a geometrical description of the linear transformation associated with the matrices"

And then i was given 4 2/2 matatrice like $$\begin{bmatrix} 3&0 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Do i just find the diagonal and P (i forgot its real name) as and $P^-1$

Such that

A = $PDP^{-1}$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3&0 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} $$

Then try to somehow make note if these are a "shear", "orthogonal projection (through line or on the origin or not)", "rotation",

The diagonal $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&3\end{bmatrix}$ kinda makes sense as an expansion by 3 $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is just none sense.

I just need help with the concept and what question actually wants

Comment: P is called the eigenvector and its diagonal entries consist of the eigenvalues of D.

Comment: @CivilSigma What?!?! $P$ is a *matrix* of *eigenvector**S***.  The diagonal entries of $P$ are *not* the eigenvalues.

Comment: Guys can you help with the question though?

Answer (score 0):

I think i got what the question meant. I think it just wants you to demonstrate the characteristics of the relationship of an eigenvalue with its eigenvector. A matrix A is scaled by the eigenvalue in the direction of the eigen vector.

So for my example. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are 3, $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} $  and 1,$\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix} $ So the matrix is scaled by 3 in the direction $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} $ and 1  in the direction $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix} $.